# How to send these items in the combo box

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

I have created a combo box in my program. I have a function named `add()` which adds some files to the drive specified.

I searched Google on how to get the list of drives present in the computer, and found this:

```
DWORD var1 = 100;
WCHAR storeValue[100];
DWORD drives = GetLogicalDriveStrings(var1, storeValue);
for (int i = 0;i < 100;i++)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I want to add the drives present in the computer to the combo box, so that my function can add files to the specified drive.  How can I do this?  It is quiet tricky for a beginner.

I am very well aware this will be easier when we create something to browse the drive but I wish to do this in my combo box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetLogicalDriveStrings` fills your buffer with a double-null terminated array of strings. You can iterate through like this, stopping when the first character of the "next" string is null.

```
wchar_t szDrives[MAX_PATH];
if (GetLogicalDriveStrings(MAX_PATH, szDrives))
{
    wchar_t* pDrive = szDrives;
    while (*pDrive)
    {
        // do something with pDrive

        // jump to next
        pDrive += wcslen(pDrive) + 1;
    }
}
```

Now the "do something with pDrive" can in your case add the string to a combo box:

```
        SendMessage(hwndCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(pDrive));
```

Comment: `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` returns each drive in `"X:\"` format, so the buffer will never need more than ((26*4)+1) = 105 characters (`MAX_PATH` is 260), and you can use `pDrive += 4` instead of `pDrive += (wcslen(pDrive) + 1)` since `wcslen()` will always be 3.

Comment: Also, `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` is `TCHAR`-based, so you should use a `TCHAR[]` buffer. And `CB_ADDSTRING` is Ansi or Unicode depending on whether `CreateWindow(Ex)A()` or `CreateWindow(Ex)W()` is used. So it makes sense to use `TCHAR[]` for `CB_ADDSTRING` as well. If you want to use `wchar_t` explicitly, you should use `GetLogicalDriveStringsW()` and `CreateWindow(Ex)W()` explicitly to match.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Also I'm sorry but TCHAR? Seriously? Has your account been hacked or something?

Comment: hey, you are one who showed an example that calls a `TCHAR`-based API, so you should show how to use a `TCHAR`-based buffer with it. Otherwise, show a Unicode-only example instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My example is Unicode only; it won't compile otherwise.